# First letter Capitalize and other letters in lower case in css?

Tags: css, text

```
<p>THIS IS SOMETEXT</p>
```

I want to make it look like `This is sometext` which the first letter of the paragraph is uppercase.
Is it possible in CSS?

**Edit:** All my text is in capital letters.

Comment: <span class="text-capitalize">Portfolio</span> this is working fine..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use `text-transform` in order to make each word of a paragraph capitalized, as follows:

```css
p { text-transform: capitalize; }
```

It's supported in [**IE4+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform#Browser_compatibility). **[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/detabopa/1/edit)**.

> **[16.5 Capitalization: the 'text-transform' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#caps-prop)**
>
> This property controls capitalization effects of an element's text.
>
> `capitalize`
>   Puts the first character of each word in uppercase; other
>   characters are unaffected.

---

### Making each word of an uppercase text, capitalized:

*The following was under this assumption:*

> I want to make it look like: `This Is Sometext`

You have to wrap each word by a wrapper element like `<span>` and use [`:first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3afirst-letter) pseudo element in order to transform the first letter of each word:

```
<p>
  <span>THIS</span> <span>IS</span> <span>SOMETEXT</span>
</p>
```

```css
p { text-transform: lowercase; }    /* Make all letters lowercase */
p > span { display: inline-block; } /* :first-letter is applicable to blocks */

p > span:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;        /* Make the first letters uppercase      */
}
```

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/fazabedo/2/edit)**.

Alternatively, you could use JavaScript to wrap each word by a `<span>` element:

```javascript
var words = $("p").text().split(" ");
$("p").empty();

$.each(words, function(i, v) {
    $("p").append($("<span>").text(v)).append(" ");
});
```

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/detabopa/4/edit)**.

---

### Making the first letter of an uppercase text, capitalized:

This seems to be what you are really looking for, that's pretty simple, all you need to do is making all words lowercase and then transforming the first letter of the paragraph to uppercase:

```javascript
p { text-transform: lowercase; }

p:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/fazabedo/1/edit)**.

Comment: But all my text is in capital letters

Comment: Seem like you misunderstood the question. I think OP want to convert `THIS IS SOMETEXT` to `This is Sometext`

Comment: Not sure the OP want `This is Sometext` or `This is sometext` since he has provided the solution below. However, +1 for your effort :)

Comment: @Felix The question is misleading. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, the OP's "answer" provided a different solution that the question asked LOL.

Comment: Use `display: inline-block` if trying to do this with a span

Answer (score 20):

Try This :

```css
p {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

p:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

#### Note

The parent of the text **need** to have the style `block` or `inline-block` or it wont work.

Comment: for anyone who wants to use the pseudo element :first-letter consider that the parent of the text should have the style block or inline-block, my text was in a span element and I was wondering why it doesn't work! now you know ;)

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out

```
p {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

p:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: This was the **exact** answer that @Tamil Selvan provided and deleted due to your comment.