# Capitalizing the first letter of a label element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting some external html page where all the data is coming in lowercase. with css, i tried to capitalize the first intial of the complete label tag but i am unable to do it, it makes complete uppercase like this:

```
.fontmodal {
     text-transform:capitalize !important;
}
```

but that did not worked...

`<table><fieldset><div><label>DATA</label></div></fieldset></table>` - This is the current Structure

Now i am trying to same in jquery, i am not sure what and how to proceed.

Here is my code what i am trying:

```
$('#Container2').find("table>label").css(textTransform,'capitalize');
```

Comment: text transform.. uppercase..

Comment: @Pogrindis It's capitalize for the first letter, uppercase is the whole text

Comment: Your HTML doesn't show any element with the fontmodal class. Could you write a fiddle ?

Comment: did you try .css("text-transform","capitalize");

Comment: class is applied to `div` not to the label

Comment: @stefab: i tried did not worked

Comment: The question is misleading. You say that the data is coming in lowercase but the posted code says something different.

Comment: @SW4 Duplicate questions should be closed as *duplicate*.

Comment: @HashemQolami - I am acutely aware of that, however *this is not a duplicate*. The answer in the linked question does not work here. This relates to `:first-letter` and block level elements - therefore either the `display` of the label needs to be set, or the `:first-letter` applied to the parent `div`. Neither was the case for the answer previously linked as a duplicate, which may not have helped future incoming traffic looking for help relating to a `label`.

Comment: @SW4 Not agreed, [it pretty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566468/first-letter-capitalize-and-other-letters-in-lower-case-in-css/22566500#22566500) works in this case (check out the last part and the OP only needs to replace `p` with `div` selector). Even for the `label`s it has mentioned that `::first-letter` is not applicable to inline elements.

Comment: You have not corrected the question, and your markup is invalid. The *actual* markup is relevant, since it affects the suitability of different approaches. And you should not confuse the issue by referring to jQuery when this is apparently a matter of HTML and CSS only (and once solved, trivial to implement in jQuery if needed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See below:

```css
label {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

div::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <label>DATA</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</table>
```

Comment: Note, for IE8 you need to use a single colon, `:first-letter`

Comment: best answer in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the HTML and need to apply the capital letter on the first letter, you need to change the default display property of the `<label>` tag :

**:first-letter :**

> has only an effect on elements with a display value of block,
>   inline-block, table-cell, list-item or table-caption. In all other
>   cases, ::first-letter has no effect. ([source MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter))

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
label::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      <label>DATA</label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simplify it and do something like below.

```js
$(document ).ready(function() {
$("label").addClass("capitalizer"); // Adjust specificity as needed
});
```

```css
.capitalizer {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 72px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: red;
    } 

.capitalizer::first-letter {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <label>data</label>
    </div>
```

**Note:** I prefer **.addClass** because **.CSS** adds inline css to your HTML and that's not advisable.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the CSSS selector `:first-letter`.

The subtly I have found is that it doesn't appear to be supported on the `<label/>` tag (didn't work in my demo code, anyhow)

But we can get round that:

```
label {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
div:first-child:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: red;
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/30trmm3w/1**

Answer (score -1):

I don't get what's wrong a simple CSS rule should do the trick :

```
#Container2 label {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but try it, it won't work. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/uLd5dhwm/

Comment: I don't get it "all the data is coming in lowercase" "i tried to capitalize the first intial of the complete label tag".
The CSS rule should work unless something is conflicting with it (like text-transform:uppercase on a higher priority selector)

Comment: It doesn't work because `capitalize` assumes that the content is **already lowercase**, hence it just capitalises the first letter, **nothing more**. The problem here is that **everything is already uppercase**, so `capitalize` won't change that.